# Unable to receive a Failure from a scala Future

Tags: scala, promise, future

Any idea why the code below can handle the `Success` without any issues, but when trying to return a `Failure` ends up throwing an `Exception`?

Exception in thread "main" au.com.ingdirect.splunk.Implicits.package$LameExcuse: hello
    at au.com.ingdirect.splunk.Implicits.package$RichJob$$anonfun$asFuture$1.apply(package.scala:42)
    at au.com.ingdirect.splunk.Implicits.package$RichJob$$anonfun$asFuture$1.apply(package.scala:36)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)

This is my code:

```
/* --- Main.scala --- */
import test.Implicits._
val job = service.createJob("search immediatePayment", queryArgs)
Await.result(job, 10 seconds)

job.onComplete{
    case Success(j) => println("Success!!")
    case Failure(l: LameExcuse) => println("Why I never fall here?") 
}

/* --- package.scala ---*/
package object Implicits {
implicit val executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4)
implicit val executionContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(executorService)

case class LameExcuse(msg: String) extends Exception(msg)

implicit class RichJob(val job: Job) {
  def asFuture(): Future[Job] = {
    // I promise i will return a completed Job
    val p = Promise[Job]()
    val fail = false
    // ... and here i am
    future {       
        while (!job.isDone()) {
          Thread.sleep(1000)
        }
        if (fail)
          p failure (new LameExcuse("Service unavailable")) //<-- This will print the stacktrace on the console, but it will not send a Failure
        else
          p success job //<-- This works fine
    } 
    p.future

  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I dont see anything wrong with the code. Can you explain the stacktrace on where exactly the exception is thrown..

Comment: LameExcuse extends Exception, try to get rid of that. BTW: 'new' is useless for case classes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think part of your issue is that in Main.scala, you are first performing a blocking `Await.result` before you register your non-blocking `onComplete` callback.  With `Await.result`, if the `Future` is failed, whatever exception the `Failure` is wrapping will be thrown all the way out.  So, in your case, if the `Future` is failed, you will never get to the code where you register the `onComplete` callback.  If you remove the `Await.result`, things should work as expected for you, more gracefully failing and hitting your `Failure` case in the `onComplete` callback.

In addition, in `asFuture`, I'm not sure why you need that `Promise`.  You already created a `Future` and can just return that as opposed to using a `Promise`.  Your code could be simplified to:

```
def asFuture(): Future[Job] = {
  val fail = false
  future {       
      while (!job.isDone()) {
        Thread.sleep(1000)
      }
      if (fail)
        throw new LameExcuse("Service unavailable")          
      job
  } 
}
```